# How do I upgrade thunar from 1.2.1 to 1.2.2 and beyond

Tags: upgrade, updates, xfce, thunar

I'm looking to upgrade my Thunar from 1.2.1 to version 1.2.1 (I'm running 11.04).  My reasoning is that I am growing tired of waiting 30 seconds for Thunar to open after a reboot (I believe this is an issue with gvfs-backends). I understand that Ubuntu 11.10 comes with Thunar 1.2.2 and no longer has this issue.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: check in packages.ubuntu.com for the version you want, download it and install it.

Answer (score 1):

Open Synaptic Manager or if you prefer Ubuntu software Center and type Thunar.
In synaptic would look like:

[image]

right-click - mark for installation - apply

Comment: ... so are you saying v1.2.2 is available to be installed in Natty even though thunar would be already installed at v1.2.1 in synaptic?  Are you sure you can ... I'm doubtful.